# update object using id in angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have an array with two keys like id and selected values its like below

```
$scope.overview =[{'id':1,'selectedvalues':[a,e,o]},{'id':2,'selectedvalues':[aa,ee,oo]},{'id':3,'selectedvalues':[aaa,eee,ooo]}];
```

I need to update after i am adding values 'h' for id =1 i need to update my array like

```
$scope.overview =[{'id':1,'selectedvalues':[a,e,o,h]},{'id':2,'selectedvalues':[aa,ee,oo]},{'id':3,'selectedvalues':[aaa,eee,ooo]}];
```

there is any other way in anuglar js currently i am handling in javascript like

```
if (this.selectedCategoryOverview.length > 0) {

    for (var i in updateDropown) {

       if (catid == updateDropown[i].id){
        overviewUpdate = false;

          updateDropown[i].selectedValues = tempSelectValuesArray;
       }

    }

    }
    if(overviewUpdate){
        this.selectedCategoryOverview.push({
        'id': catid,
        'selectedValues': tempSelectValuesArray
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using filter,

```
var found;

if (this.selectedCategoryOverview.length > 0) {
    found = $filter('filter')($scope.updateDropown, { id: catid });
    if (found.length)
        $scope.updateDropown = tempSelectValuesArray;
}

if (found && found.length) {
    this.selectedCategoryOverview.push({
        'id': catid,
        'selectedValues': tempSelectValuesArray
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `array.find` to find existing overview by id. If `find` method returns a value - just update the value, and add the value otherwise.

In pseudocode:

```
foundObject = array.find()
if(foundObject)
  update()
else
  pushNew()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would not make much difference if you do it angular way or JS way unless DOM is involved, so here is one angular way which is nothing but cloated JS way,

```
 function pushNewArrayValue(value){
  angular.forEach($scope.overview,function(arr,i){
   arr.selectedValue.push(value);
  })
 }

 pusheNewArrayValue('h')
```